# CJUIDatePicker with CGridView doesn't work

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to include a Datepicker inside the CGridView as follows, the datepicker widget is used within the Grid View.

```
this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'order-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'order_id',
    'customer.address.firstname',
    'customer.address.lastname',
    /*array('name' => 'ordering_date',
        'value' => 'date("M j, Y", $data->ordering_date)'),
    */  

    array('name'=>'ordering_date',
                    'value'=>'$data->ordering_date',     
                    'filter'=>$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                                                    'model'=>$model,
                                                    'attribute'=>'ordering_date',
                                                    'options'=>array(
                                                            'showButtonPanel'=>true,
                                                            'changeYear'=>true,
                                                            )
                                                    ),
                                                    true),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'80','style'=>'text-align:center'),
            ),             
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn', 
        'template' => '{view} {rollback} {receive}{pack} {dispatch}{delivered}',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'250px'),

        'buttons'=>array(
            'receive'=>array(
                'id'=>'receive',
                'name'=>'receive',
                'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/shop/order/admin&received=true", array("id"=>$data->order_id,"asDialog"=>1,"gridId"=>$this->grid->id))',
                'type'=>'submit',
                'imageUrl'=>'/mdg/images/Receive1.png',
                'visible'=>'($data->status=="pending")?true:false;'
             ),
             'pack'=>array(
                'id'=>'pack',
                'name'=>'pack',
                'type'=>'submit',
                'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/shop/order/admin&packed=true", array("id"=>$data->order_id,"asDialog"=>1,"gridId"=>$this->grid->id))',
                'click'=>'',
                'imageUrl'=>'/mdg/images/pack1.png',
                'visible'=>'($data->status=="received")?true:false;'
             ),
             'dispatch'=>array(
                'id'=>'dispatch',
                'name'=>'dispatch',
                'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/shop/order/admin&dispatched=true", array("id"=>$data->order_id,"asDialog"=>1,"gridId"=>$this->grid->id))',
                'click'=>'',
                'imageUrl'=>'/mdg/images/dispatch.png',
                'visible'=>'($data->status=="packed")?true:false;'
             ),
             'delivered'=>array(
                'id'=>'delivered',
                'name'=>'delivered',
                'url'=>'',
                'click'=>'',
                'imageUrl'=>'/mdg/images/delivered1.png',
                'visible'=>'($data->status=="dispatched")?true:false;'
             ),
             'rollback'=>array(
                'id'=>'rollback',
                'name'=>'rollback',
                'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/shop/order/admin&rollback=true", array("id"=>$data->order_id,"asDialog"=>1,"gridId"=>$this->grid->id))',
                'click'=>'',
                'imageUrl'=>'/mdg/images/rollback.jpg',
                'visible'=>'($data->status=="pending")?false:true;'
             ),
        ),
    ),


'status',

),
'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(){
                                    jQuery("#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'ordering_date').'").datepicker({showButtonPanel:true, changeYear:true});
                            }',
```

)); ?>

This Code was taken from a suggestion given in the yiiframework forum. But it doesnt do anything.

Any idea why that is?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be an easier approach.

Comment: i want to give the user the option to select a date via the date picker and then filter according to that. Is there a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would put the date picker in the `_search` view. If you used Gii to generate your CRUD, it should already be there, available from the `admin` view:

`<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">

<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->`

Comment: ya i know.. But then since the page refreshes everytime you search via that search panel, i thot it's better to give the date picker in the CGridView itself, where it finds the results through ajax. Any Idea why my code doesnt work?

Comment: oh!! damn... ya.. sorry ma bad!! i am a newbee in the yii framework.. Then ill do that!! thanks alot!!